# How can I include Greek letters?

Tags: support, questions

[Letters from the Greek alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet#Letters) are used in physics, mathematics, chemistry, etc. However, I cannot include them in my questions as they aren't available on the standard Android keyboard.

Comment: What’s wrong with `$\alpha$`?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft. Not all sites have MathJax enabled.

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen: Yes, but the mentioned sites (or sites about the mentioned topics) do. This suggest that the asker’s problem is a different one.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Thank you I did not knew about mathjax but now I will Google it.

Comment: @user14530. The sites with MathJax enabled have extensive help documentation on their meta sites.

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen  Thank you.

Comment: As for the keyboard, there are dozens (if not hundreds) of keyboard replacement apps freely available in the Google Play Store. Surely some of them have Greek characters available.

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce  How can i know which one contains them and also I cannot download them all.

Comment: [Search](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=greek%20alphabet%20keyboard&c=apps)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am assuming that you mean how can you include them in answers on SE, in the markdown editor.  You can just use the HTML equivalent, so for example if you are on SE.Electronics, and you need the unit of resistance, Ω, just type `&Omega;`

You can get the upper and lower case letters by changing the case of the first letter in the name, i.e for ω, type `&omega;`

You can find the respective HTML greek character codes on [UTF-8 Greek and Coptic](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_greek.asp), but is quite intuitive so you shouldn't need to look each one up.

> Α `&Alpha;` α `&alpha;`
> Β `&Beta;`  β `&beta;`
> Γ `&Gamma;` γ `&gamma;`

and so on.

All of the characters used in these HTML codes are, or should be, available on your Android keyboard.

Comment: How do I do this in a code block? When I use the backtick or add in 4 spaces at the beginning of the line, it uses the literal values of ampersand and semicolon!

Comment: @PlastyGrove - I may be wrong but I don't think that you can. Why do you need to use them in a code block, instead of blockquotes? Code block is usually reserved for command line input and/or output, which is _typically_ ASCII only..

Comment: Yea, that makes sense, thanks! I used blockquotes instead.